# How to retain ViewContoller when popped Objective -C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How do you retain a view contoller when its is popped from the stack ?

Basically i have an Mp3 Player view controller. When i'm in that view controller, i can play music. when the music is playing and i navigate to a different controller, The music stops playing, and when i navigate back to that controller, it starts another instance of it. so my guess for a fix, will probably be to retain the view controller ?

This is how i initiate my music player view controller:

```
NSString *songLargeArtworkURL = [self.songArtworkURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"large" withString:@"crop"];
MusicPlayerViewController *musicPlayer = [[MusicPlayerViewController alloc] init];
musicPlayer.songName = self.testString;
musicPlayer.songArtWork = songLargeArtworkURL;
musicPlayer.songStream = self.songStreamURL;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:musicPlayer animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a local variable for `MusicPlayerViewController`, use an instance variable. Only for the first time, allocate the `musicPlayer` instance. Shown below:

```
NSString *songLargeArtworkURL = [self.songArtworkURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"large" withString:@"crop"];
if(! musicPlayer) {
    musicPlayer = [[MusicPlayerViewController alloc] init];
}
musicPlayer.songName = self.testString;
musicPlayer.songArtWork = songLargeArtworkURL;
musicPlayer.songStream = self.songStreamURL;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:musicPlayer animated:YES];
```

The above code makes sure that, only for the first time the music player is instantiated. Subsequent times, it pushes the same instance of the music player

Comment: i tried this already but i got an error:  Application tried to push a nil view controller on target

Comment: Are you sure, you are allocating it in the first place?

Comment: Is this there:    
if(! musicPlayer) {
    musicPlayer = [[MusicPlayerViewController alloc] init];
}

Comment: "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target" error comes when u push a nil object. Hence if you allocate the instance for the first time, you should not be getting this error. My guess is that you haven't instantiated the instance for the first time. Can you post the code that you have tried

Comment: Oh i think i found the problem. the mp3 player comes after 2 view from
and i just realised when i pop, it takes it back to the very first view so that makes a new instance of the 2nd view so that makes it nil. if you get what i mean, Thanks alot ! though i tought of this, i didn't know it was the right way of doing it :)